# How to return previous version of Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I downloaded the new build 3103(from 9 February) and found, that my favourite theme Spacegray was changed. Specifically, symbols which were white color now are red - https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBWYh.png. Html and Css wasn't changed. Just JS. It is awful and ugly! Help me, please. Thanks you!

Comment: There is a lot of upheaval with the JavaScript syntax now, with commits being made several times a day to the [official repo](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=javascript). I wouldn't completely give up on 3103, but instead keep an eye on the JS issues and pull when things seem to be more settled. I don't know if sublimehq will release another public beta then or not, but the advantages of using 3103 outweigh the JS disadvantages currently. If you wish, ask a new question about how to replace just the JS syntax from 3103 with the one from 3083, and I can help you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can take the link from the [official website](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) and change the version number in the URL.

For example, if you want the [3100 version](https://download.sublimetext.com/Sublime%20Text%20Build%203100%20x64%20Setup.exe) instead of [3103 version](https://download.sublimetext.com/Sublime%20Text%20Build%203103%20x64%20Setup.exe)

Comment: Thanks you! It helped me, but I don't have access to make this answer the best

Comment: Strange, but no problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Sakuto's example is for Windows, for OSX, if you want to download, say, build 3126, you would change the current build # (which is 3143, as of this post date):
https://download.sublimetext.com/Sublime%20Text%20Build%20**3143**.dmg

to

https://download.sublimetext.com/Sublime%20Text%20Build%20**3126**.dmg